# Is it wise to send Emails to IRCC using Webforms in order to prioritise visa applications?

Tags: visas, canada, paperwork, nigerian-citizens

I have submitted my application for TRV.

I would be meeting with some VC's to discuss pre-seed Funding with the companies and showcase the app to them in order for them to make their observations and fund the project. There is no invitation, so I am making an open proposal of my solution for funding, and I am supposed to meet with the investors by August.

Can I send emails to IRCC using Webforms in order for them to prioritise the application in order to have speedy responses?

Comment: Prioritization of visa applications is usually done by paying extra for it when applying... It is **very unlikely** that doing something like that would work. Especially as the [lead time](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/application/check-processing-times.html) is 766 days in Nigeria